# add modal to woocommerce add to cart button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, bootstrap-modal

I am building a wordpress site with woocommerce.

I want to add an optional insurance product that pops up when a customer clicks on 'add to cart' for a particular product. The idea is that they have to accept or decline this product before they continue to the checkout.

I have tried using bootstrap modal but I can't get it to trigger using the add to cart button. 
Modal is working fine as a specific modal button built into the page, so I know it's not a problem with jquery or bootstrap, but I can't figure out how link it to the add to cart button.

Seems like something that should be built-in to woocommerce already but if it is I've missed it.

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting the modal to trigger when the cart page opened, as the cart page is Wordpress it was straight-forward. Not the perfect solution as the modal now opens when a customer goes to buy any product, but it's better than nothing. 
here's the code with the default content

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
       </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

and the js

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myModal').modal('show')
 });
  });
 </script>
```

I inserted all this directly in the 'your cart' wordpress page.

Works fine, but I'd love to hear a better solution

Answer (score 1):

by adding a query to checks if current url contains the string 'add-to-cart', you can show the modal in your shop page. You should also uncheck 'Redirect to the cart page after successful addition' under: WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("add-to-cart") != -1){
        $('#cartModal').modal('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

[woocommerce add to cart popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-woocart-popup-lite)

use this plugin to generate the popup.

hope this helps !

Comment: thanks for that, but I can't figure out how to use it!

Comment: I've uploaded it, and changed the file permissions but I don't see where to add it to a product??

Comment: you need to google it. i have just show the path.. you need to finish... like this only so many things will come.  try yourself :) ...