# Modify a plugin in woocommerce to insert a modal after add to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to create a modal box after click the add to cart button. But just if a checkbox is selected and inside an input there is a msg.

So I think the best way would be inside the function where the plugin, after the add to cart button is clicked, send the data to woocommerce.

Here it is the function

```
/**
     * When added to cart, save any gift wrap data
     *
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $cart_item_meta
     * @param mixed $product_id
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_cart_item_data ($cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        $is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

        if ( $is_wrappable == '' && $this->gift_wrap_enabled )
            $is_wrappable = 'yes';

        if ( !empty( $_POST['gift_wrap'] ) && $is_wrappable == 'yes' )
            $cart_item_meta['gift_wrap'] = true;

        if ( !empty( $_POST['gift_wrap_selection'] ) && $is_wrappable == 'yes' )
            $cart_item_meta['gift_wrap_selection'] = strip_tags( $_POST['gift_wrap_selection'] );

        if ( !empty( $_POST['gift_wrap_inner_message'] ) && $is_wrappable == 'yes' ){

                        $cart_item_meta['gift_wrap_inner_message'] = strip_tags( $_POST['gift_wrap_inner_message'] );
                        }
        if ( !empty( $_POST['gift_wrap_outer_message'] ) && $is_wrappable == 'yes' )
            $cart_item_meta['gift_wrap_outer_message'] = strip_tags( $_POST['gift_wrap_outer_message'] );

        return $cart_item_meta;
    }
```

I think the best way is to call a function here:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['gift_wrap_inner_message'] ) && $is_wrappable == 'yes' ){

                        $cart_item_meta['gift_wrap_inner_message'] = strip_tags( $_POST['gift_wrap_inner_message'] );
                        }
```

Comment: A modal, implies Javascript. You will need to add the the modal content to the page and then trigger it when you want it to display.

Comment: But I want to trigger it here, is that possible?

Comment: Almost everything is possible. I'm not sure where you mean by "here". After the "add to cart" button is clicked do you want to show a modal before the item is actually added to the cart (thus intercepting the add to cart process). Or do you want to show your modal after the item is in the cart? What do you want to display in your modal? Please modify your question to make it clearer what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, anything in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26784105/383847) that can help?

Comment: Here I meant in the second code I selected. In my modal I want a "confirm" button, OK/Cancel , if press cancel does not add to cart.

Comment: I cannot use the trigger directly on the button because first I have to check  if the checkbox and the msg are fill in.

Comment: Sure you can. As you can use Javascript to check if the checkbox and message are filled in. Though you should also verify that your site will work without Javascript enabled as not everyone uses Javascript.

Comment: Sidenote: adding a confirm button seems like bad user experience. Why add an additional step to the purchase process?

Comment: I know but client ask

Comment: Clients are not always right. :) but to help you further, I need to see the markup you have added and whether you've started any JavaScript.